# How to find average of secondary element in a Binary Search Tree node

Tags: c++, data-structures, recursion, traversal, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to create a function that finds the average of some data within the nodes of a tree. The problem is, every node contains two pieces of data and unlike other BSTs, the primary data from which it is built is a string. Finding the average of number-based elements in a tree isn't an issue for me, but since each node contains a string (a person's name) and a seemingly random number (the weight of said person), the tree is actually in complete disarray, and I have no idea how to deal with it. 
Here is my node so you see what I mean:

```
struct Node {
    string name;
    double weight;
    Node* leftChild;
    Node* rightChild;
};
Node* root;
```

Here's the function during one of its many stages:

```
 // This isn't what I'm actually using so don't jump to conclusions
 double nameTree::averageWeight(double total, double total, int count) const
 {
     if (parent != NULL)
     {      //nonsense, nonsense
        averageWeight(parent->leftChild, total, count);
        averageWeight(parent->rightChild, total, count);
        count++;                                 
        total = total + parent->weight;      
        return total;
     }
     return (total / count);
}
```

In an effort to traverse the tree, I tried some recursion but every time I manage to count and total everything, something gets screwey and it ends up doing return(total/count) each time. I've also tried an array implementation by traversing the tree and adding the weights to the array, but that didn't work because the returns and recursion interfered, or something.

And just because I know someone is going to ask, yes, this is for a school assignment. However, this is one out of like, 18 functions in a class so it's not like I'm asking anyone to do this for me. I've been on this one function for hours now and I've been up all night and my brain hurts so any help would be vastly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
    //total number of tree nodes
static int count=0;


 // Calculate the total sum of the weights in the tree 
double nameTree::calculateWeight(Node *parent)   
{   
    double total=0;

    if (parent != NULL)       
    {      
        //nonsense, nonsense    
        //Calculate total weight for left sub-tree
        total+=calculateWeight(parent->leftChild); 
        //Calculate weight for right sub-tree
        total+=calculateWeight(parent->rightChild);  
        //add current node weight
        total+=parent->weight;                                                       
    } 
    count++;   
    //if it is a leaf it will return 0
    return total;   
}  

double averageWeight()
{
    double weightSum;

    weightSum=calculateWeight();

    if(count!=0)
        return (weightSum/count);
    else
    {
        cout<<"The tree is empty";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I don't have a compiler here but I believe it works.

Comment: You have to walk the tree first and then check `count`. As it is `count` is initially 0 and will always be so, as `calculateWeight` will not get called.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the average you need two numbers: the total value and the number of elements in the set. You need to provide a function (recursive is probably the simplest) that will walk the tree and either return a `pair<double,int>` with those values or else modify some argument passed as reference to store the two values.

As of your code, `averageWeight` returns a `double`, but when you call it recursively you are ignoring (discarding) the result. The `count` argument is passed by copy, which means that the modifications applied in the recursive calls will not be visible by the caller (which then does not know how much `parent->weight` should *weight* towards the result.

This should be enough to get you started.